# how to show a button on top of another element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am very new to Kotlin and I want to create a simple activity where details of a person are shown with their picture.
I want to move the edit button on top of the imageView so it looks a bit better and is not in line with the other elements. The screenshot is also attached below the XML file

here is my XML file for this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingVertical="16dp"
    tools:context=".EditProfileActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="257dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <EditText
            android:background="#CFC9C9"
            android:id="@+id/txtEditFullName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Full Name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"/>

        <EditText
            android:background="#CFC9C9"
            android:id="@+id/txtEditNickname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Nickname"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

        <EditText
            android:background="#CFC9C9"
            android:id="@+id/txtEditEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Email(john@abc.com)"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

        <EditText
            android:background="#CFC9C9"
            android:id="@+id/txtEditLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Location"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

        <EditText
            android:background="#CFC9C9"
            android:id="@+id/txtEditSkills"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Skills"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

        <EditText
            android:background="#CFC9C9"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/txtEditDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="257dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to stack the views in LinearLayout. In LinearLayout you can only place the views in a row/column. If u need to place one view over another, u should use FrameLayout (simpliest variant) or ConstraintLayout